# How to modify SNAPSHOT/Qualifier to UTC+2 (Eclipse RCP/Tycho/Maven)?

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm building an Eclipse RCP application using Tycho/Maven.

My problem is that default build SNAPSHOT/Qualifier is UTC time zone.

I would like to change it to UTC+2.

How to change build timestamp to UTC+2 using Thyco/Maven to build an Eclipse RCP App ?

thks

Comment: You can configure the format used by `tycho-packaging-plugin` but the time zone is always UTC according to the [doc](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-packaging-plugin/build-qualifier-mojo.html)

Comment: Leave it a UTC. Everything else will probably cause problems.